# Not saving and verified the login on database in python

Tags: python, database, authentication, save, verification

I am doing a program where I need to do a system login saved in the database.

The program isn't saving and verifying the users in the database. Can someone help me to understand where I have gone wrong?

I am still a beginner programmer.

Thank you a lot!

```
def login():
  global screen1
  screen1 = Toplevel(screen)
  screen1.title("Login!")
  screen1.geometry("300x250")

  global username
  global password
  global username_entry
  global password_entry
  username = StringVar()
  password = StringVar()

  Label(screen1, text = "Ensira os seus dados nos campos abaixo!").pack()
  Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
  Label(screen1, text = "Utilizador * ").pack()
  username_entry = Entry(screen1, textvariable = username)
  username_entry.pack()
  Label(screen1, text = "Password * ").pack()
  password_entry =  Entry(screen1, textvariable = password)
  password_entry.pack()
  Label(screen1, text = "").pack()
  Button(screen1, text = "Entrar.", width = 10, height = 1, command = VerificarLogin).pack()


#Função para receber a password e criptografa-la para comparar 
def VerificarLogin():
    password = password_entry.get()
    encodedBytes = base64.b64encode(password.encode("utf-8"))
    passEncry = str(encodedBytes, "utf-8")

    cursor.execute("UPDATE user SET Online = '0' WHERE nome = 'admin' ")
    ConnectBD.connection.commit()
    cursor.execute("UPDATE user SET Online = '0' WHERE nome = 'Angelo' ")
    ConnectBD.connection.commit()
    cursor.execute("UPDATE user SET Online = '0' WHERE nome = 'Henrique' ")
    ConnectBD.connection.commit()



    if password.get() == "admin" and passEncry == username[0][2]:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE user SET Online = '1' WHERE nome = 'admin' ")
        ConnectBD.connection.commit()



    for x in range(len(username)):
        if password.get() == username[x][1] and passEncry == username[x][2]:
            cursor.execute("UPDATE user SET Online = '1' WHERE nome = '%s' "%(username[x][1]) )
            ConnectBD.connection.commit()
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Have you done any debugging?

Comment: this a login to other program. when the users login in the program , they will can change the database . No, i don't do nothing

Comment: please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.